# Can't get plugins to install on my Hudson CI server

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

I'm trying to stand up a Hudson CI server.

I'm following an article written [here](http://redsolo.blogspot.com/2008/04/guide-to-building-net-projects-using.html).

I've gotten the server to stand up successfully by itself, but when I go to install the plugins all the plugins fail to install.

This happens the second time I run

> java -DHUDSON_HOME=data -jar hudson.war

when I have all my plugins in the /plugins folder.

The errors I'm getting are

> No 'Plugin-Class' entry in the manifest of ...msbuild.hpi
>
> No 'Plugin-Class' entry in the manifest of ...nunit.hpi
>
> Dependency analysis-core doens't exist (related to task.hpi)

I grabbed the latest stable release of them, so I'm thinking it has something to do with how I set up my hudson instance.  The only different thing that I have done from the article is that I set up the installation in C:\Hudson.

Does anyone know why these plugins are all failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that for some reason I downloaded version 1.1 of hudson.  I'm not sure how that happened since I clicked on the latest link, but I went back and downloaded the real latest version and the plugins are installing fine now.

The tasks plugin still doesn't install, but I don't really have to have that one, I was just curious what it was.